# Is the word European the only word that doesn't go after "an?"

Tags: grammar

I can only think of the word **European** as a word that doesn't go after the word **an**. Is there any other words that start with a vowel, but don't go after **an**?

Comment: What are you asking?  "This" also doesn't go after "an".  "Purple" also doesn't.  Also, "are"...

Comment: ‘European’ does not start with a vowel _sound_, which is what matters. It starts with a ‘you’ sound, which has the consonantal /j/ as its first element.

Comment: "University".  "Union".  "Eulogy".  "Ewer".  Any word that starts with a syllable that sounds like "you".  "A"-versus-"an" is only a matter of what the word immediately after the article _sounds_ like.

Comment: And also *one*, /wan/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be true of pretty much any word that started with a "you" sound, regardless of how it is spelled since "a" or "an" is based on the pronunciation, not the spelling.

> A union
>
> A utility
>
> A eulogy, a eunuch, a euphemism, a euphoria
>
> A uniform standard of spelling, which we don't have in English
>
> A useful rule of thumb -- 'an' before vowel  -- which doesn't always work
>
> A unified mess of different linguistic sources, which compose the vocabulary of the English language.

OK, sorry, I got carried away.

Where it gets fun is where it varies by dialect. Is it "a hotel" or "an hotel"? Is it "a herb" or "an herb"? Depends on whether you are "a united states citizen".

Comment: A ewe is a female sheep

Comment: It's a /y/ sound, not a "you" sound. "You" is not a sound. The rule is very straightforward: _a_ before consonants, _an_ before vowels. In every case. ***But*** -- and here's where the hard part comes -- the vowels and consonants are pronounced, not spelled. Since lots of words spelled with U actually start with /y/, it's a consonant. Opposite situation, silent H in _hour_, starts with a vowel /aw/. If you're a native English speaker, you already know this. If you're not, learn to say it out loud; the spelling won't tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean this because *European* begins with a vowel. Try *a urologist*.